# Mass CRUD REST edit/update controller

Tags: rest, laravel, controller, crud, laravel-5.3

I am trying to create a RESTful CRUD [controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) with a little but significant difference that might be in conflict with REST idea but anyway:

I am trying to mass edit items like so `/photos/{photo}/edit` where item id parameters are like `/photos/0&2&7/edit`

What is the proper way to establish that in Laravel 5.3?
Is there a way to use some method injections or at least to receive a collection of parameters in the controller method ?

```
public function edit($id) {
    //.......
}
```

Appreciate your kind help, BR

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying you would like to be able to pass multiple ids in the photo parameter e.g. in the instance you provided ids 0, 2 and 7? Or is it one photo and the id of that photo is `0&2&7`?

Comment: @alex-greaves yes ids are 0,2 and 7 of three different items.

Comment: So you have a bunch of images, presumably in an images table with an Image model? And you'd like to return a collection of all the images with the ids specified in the photo parameter? I'm assuming that given the collection you'd be able to handle manipulating the images as necessary?

Comment: @alex-greaves yes, indeed. I was wondering what is the best way to handle it, could some method injection help and have the photos as parameters ot least having the ids as collection instead of the parameter string or any good way to handle the whole thing at all.

Comment: First, am I correctly in assuming you're using javascript to create the url? Also, would you be able to give a bit more background as to what is going on i.e. why you want/ to edit multiple images at the same time?

Comment: @RossWilson the images are just the url example consider them any kind of model, item in general. 
In my case is far more convenient for the user to edit a few items  at once and yes you are right about the url and javascript.

Comment: In that case it would make more sense to me to use ajax and submit each resource separately. The UI wouldn't necessarily have to change but this way it's staying completely RESTful and you also don't have to have any additional logic for your controllers.

Comment: @RossWilson but that means 3 extra requests to the server and 3 extra transactions to the database.

Comment: Yeah, I know. You're right in that fewer requests/calls is technically better but this is the RESTful approach. Also, unless you're editing the resources with the exact same data your going to be making 3 calls to the database anyway. As for the requests, I would say you're possibly trying to optimise prematurely for something that should be a pretty low cost but potentially at the expense of making your code base more bloated. All that being said @alex-greaves answer below should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Eloquent you can do whereIn, so you just need to explode the photo parameter so that all the ids are in an array:

```
public function edit($ids) {
    $photo_ids = explode('&', $ids);

    $images = Image::whereIn('id', $photo_ids)->get();
}
```

You can switch out statically accessing the Image model like I did in this example, you can just method inject or dependency inject the image model, let me know if you'd like assistance with dependency/method injection.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i guess you are trying Model binding so you have to use like this

```
public function edit(Photo $photo) {
    //.......
}
```

Your route should like this

```
Route::model('photos','App\Photo');
Route::resource('photos','PhotoController');
```

or you can try this way 
your route and function like this

```
Route::resource('photos','PhotoController');

public function edit($id) {
    $photo = Photo::findorFail($id);
}
```

Comment: then explain your question properly